# Cassandra performance testing tools

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to run performance tests for a 6 node datastax cassandra cluster.

Could anyone tell me if they run the cassandra stress test alone or use any other tool to get the performance results?

If so can anyone suggest me which tools are good to run performance tests on cassandra cluster? I tried searching and found Yahoo benchmarking tool but would like to get your suggestion before I run the tests.

Answer (score 3):

Besides mentioned by you Yahoo benchmarking tool there is Cassandra-stress tool, along with [benchmarking any schema](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/improved-cassandra-2-1-stress-tool-benchmark-any-schema).

Depending on the use case, I would also wrote a proof of concept client (with library you want to use in the future) and tried to simulate future test load (something like integration-stress test).